# How to select just one record for each particular value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I created which have the following columns:

- Table 1: MediaID, CurrentIndex, isUsing
- Table 2: Table2ID, MediaID, NewIndex

I want to make a query which checks the following things

1. `IsUsing` is null or false in Table1
2. Return the top 1 from table2 if `NewIndex` is greater than `currentIndex` for each `MediaID`. Like this

   ```
   SELECT TOP 1 * 
   FROM table2 
   ORDER BY NewIndex DESC
   ```

Is it possible to combine these two statements into one?

Reason being, I am doing this query using C#, and the first query returns more than 200+ records. I don't want to be sending 200+ database requests checking every time.

Input like this

```
+-----------+--+----------+--------------+--+
|  MediaID  |  | IsUsing  | CurrentIndex |  |
+-----------+--+----------+--------------+--+
| 123123123 |  | false    |            2 |  |
|    123321 |  |          |            0 |  |
|    123123 |  | false    |            5 |  |
+-----------+--+----------+--------------+--+


+-----------+-----------+----------+--+--+--+
| Table2ID  |  MediaID  | NewIndex |  |  |  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--+--+--+
|         1 | 123123123 |        3 |  |  |  |
|         2 |    123321 |        2 |  |  |  |
|         3 |    123123 |        0 |  |  |  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--+--+--+
```

So the output would be like

MediaID,Table2ID,Index(from table2)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. Once you decide you should start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You said you are using C#. You are looking for a solution in C# or sql ?

Comment: I am using SQL, looking for the answer in SQL itself

Comment: what are your output columns, please add column names and output

Comment: AFAIK there is no RDBMS named SQL. Perhaps you are using SQL Server? How do you connect to the DB engine from C# code?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i am using SQL connection to connect to the SQL server

Comment: OK great now we know we are using sql server. How about some details of your tables, Sample data and desired output? See the link in the comment way up there at the top. Without some details we are left guessing what you might want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT t2.MediaID, t2.Table2ID, t2.NewIndex,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.MediaID 
                             ORDER BY t2.NewIndex DESC) AS rn
   FROM table2 AS t2
   JOIN table1 AS t1 
      ON t2.MediaID = t1.MediaID AND t2.NewIndex > t1.CurrentIndex
   WHERE (t1.IsUsing IS NULL) OR (t1.IsUsing = 0)
)
SELECT MediaID, Table2ID, NewIndex
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

The query of the `CTE`:

- Filters out `table1` records having `IsUsing` set to 1 (this is the `bit` value for `true`)
- Filters out `table2` records having `NewIndex` less than or equal to `CurrentIndex` of `table1`.

Finally, using `ROW_NUMBER()` we can get the greatest-per-MediaID record.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that `apply` is simpler for this type of query:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.mediaid = t1.mediaid and t2.NewIndex > t1.currentIndex
      order by t2.NewIndex desc
     ) t2
where t1.isUsing is null or t1.isUsing = 'false';
```

You will note that this query very much follows the logic in how you described the question.  In addition, `apply` tends to do a better job of making use of indexes (in this case, on `table2(mediaid, newindex)`) than `row_number()` does.